# What is the probability that he escapes the island?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A man is stranded on an island. A benevolent genie presents three boxes, 23 white marbles, and 7 black marbles and instructs the man, "You may distribute the marbles into the boxes any way you see fit, but you must use all of the marbles. Once you finish, you will choose a box at random and then choose a marble from the box at random. If the marble is whiten, then I will help you escape from this place.

**Assuming the man distributes the marbles in his best interest, what is the probability that he escapes the island?**

Apart from the first two cases, the probability that the man draws a white marble from the box is $3/4$

$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)(1)+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)(1)+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{11}{12}$

This might solve my problem but my brain still keeps bugging about the outcome.

The main question arises: Why this choice is optimal? I started to think why we are analyzing the  chance of escaping than not escaping.

When I tried to solve this, while splitting up the marbles into multiple boxes: again its not optimal.

How can I find an optimal way of explanation to this now?

Comment: Um... you never actually stated how you would have the man distribute the marbles.  And actually I don't see have you get $\frac 23$ I get if I put one marble in box 1 and 2 and all the rest in box 3.

Comment: What are the 3 cases you speak of?

Comment: @Alan The OP thinks the optimal distribution of the marbles is that two of the boxes contain one marble each, and the last box contains $21$ white marbles and $7$ black marbles. In that case, if you pick a box at random, then "the first two cases" are the first two boxes where the probability of drawing a white ball is $1$. In the last one, it's $\frac 34$. That leads to a possible answer, and the OP doesn't know why it's the best (or if it is).

Comment: before optimizing, i took two drastic cases in which, case:I one chest might not have any white marbles. If we pick that box, we stay on island without any doubt. The other two boxes might let us give a chance to escape with a prob of $<=1$ If you can understand this rest is math @fleablood

Comment: No, I understood your reasoning perfectly.  But you never actually *stated* what you were *using* that strategy in your body.  (I did make calculation error that I mistakenly assume $\frac {21}{21+ 7} = \frac 23$.  That's a "D'oh!"

Comment: Check.  It's easy to show that the best you can do is have one box with a 1/4 losing potential and the other two with nonzero losing potentials if you split it any other way.  Showed that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is just a more rigorous write-up of things, because there is a more general phenomena here that is in play : an exchange argument.

Summary :

- The "success probability" calculation
- The idea of an exchange argument.
- Using the exchange argument to show black-ball exchange optimality.
- Using the exchange argument to restrict the colors of balls in an optimal configuration of boxes.
- Resolving the remaining cases by hand.
- A small addendum on the technique used.

---

###### The "success probability"

Suppose that you put $a_1,a_2,a_3$ white balls in boxes $1,2,3$ respectively, and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ black balls in boxes $1,2,3$ respectively.

Then, the probability of getting a white ball when you pick a box at random, and then pick a ball out of it at random, is (by Bayes' rule) $$
\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}\right]
$$

Note that $a_1+a_2+a_3 = 23$ and $b_1+b_2+b_3 = 7$. Therefore, we're basically trying to maximize $$
\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}
$$

subject to those summation conditions.

---

###### The "exchange" argument

There is a very common idea in optimal control theory (a branch of mathematics that can be studied from a pure, or applied point of view) that's called the exchange argument. It roughly says the following : if a particular arrangement (or control) is not optimal, then it can be made better just by exchanging two "components" of that arrangement (or control).

The idea here, is that the structure of the "reward" (in this case, the success probability) allows us to execute an exchange argument : a procedure that will always increase the reward, provided that it can be done.

For example, suppose that we're given the configuration of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ white balls and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ black balls in boxes $1,2,3$ respectively. Suppose that $b_1>0$.

Create the alternate configuration by taking a black ball from the first box and putting it in the third box. Now, you have $b_1-1,b_2,b_3+1$ black balls instead.

Compare the success probabilities now. Initially, it is $$
\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3}
\right]
$$

Following the exchange, it becomes $$
\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1-1}+\frac{a_2}{a_2+b_2}+\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3+1}
\right]
$$

Their difference (times $3$, let's avoid the $\frac 13$ for now) is $$
\frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3+1} - \frac{a_3}{a_3+b_3} - \frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1}+\frac{a_1}{a_1+b_1-1}
$$

which equals $$
\frac{a_1}{(a_1+b_1)(a_1+b_1-1)}- \frac{a_3}{(a_3+b_3+1)(a_3+b_3)}
$$

This is positive precisely when $$
a_3(a_1+b_1)(a_1+b_1-1) < a_1(a_3+b_3)(a_3+b_3+1)
$$

To write that more cleanly, let $a_1+b_1 = T_1,a_2+b_2 = T_2,a_3+b_3 = T_3$ be the total number of balls in boxes $1,2,3$ respectively in the initial configuration. Then this condition becomes
$$
a_3T_1(T_1-1) < a_1T_3(T_3+1) 
$$

Thus, if the original configurations satisfy this inequality and if $b_1>0$, then the exchange argument shows that a better configuration exists.

I will refer to the above condition as an "exchange" inequality, because it provides a criteria for when an exchange leads to a better configuration.

---

###### A result on "extremal" black ball values being the best

With respect to this exchange, let's make the following observation. Suppose that $b_1>0$ and $a_1T_3(T_3+1) > a_3T_1(T_1-1)$. Then, we make the exchange : take a black ball from box $1$ and put it in box $3$.

However, if we now look at the number of black and white balls in boxes $1$ and $3$, then the new left hand side is $a_1(T_3+1)(T_3+2)$, and the new right hand side is $a_3(T_1-1)(T_1-2)$. We would still have
$$
a_1(T_3+1)(T_3+2) > a_1T_3(T_3+1) > a_3T_1(T_1-1)>a_3(T_1-1)(T_1-2)
$$

That is, we have proven the following :

> If it is better for us to transfer a black ball from box $1$ to box $3$, then (if feasible) it is still better for us to transfer another black ball from box $1$ to box $3$, because this retains the "exchange" inequality we wrote above.

By inductive reasoning, we obtain the following statement :

> If it is better for us to transfer a black ball from box $1$ to box $3$, then the best possible situation is that all the black balls from box $1$ are transferred to box $3$.

---

###### A result on the colors of the balls that can be in each box

We must prove now is that if two boxes have a positive number of black and white balls, then by exchanging black balls among these boxes we can produce better configurations. That is the following lemma :

> If $a_1,a_3,b_1,b_3>0$, then at least one of $a_1T_3(T_3-1)<a_3T_1(T_1+1)$ or $a_3T_1(T_1-1)<a_1T_3(T_3+1)$ must be true.

Proof : If both are false, then $$
a_1T_3(T_3-1) \geq a_3T_1(T_1+1) , a_3T_1(T_1-1)\geq a_1T_3(T_3+1)
$$
are both true. However, $$
a_3T_1(T_1+1)> a_3T_1(T_1-1)
$$
because $a_3,T_1>0$. Therefore, $a_1T_3(T_3-1)> a_1T_3(T_3+1)$. This can't be true because $a_1,T_3>0$.

Combining this with the previous lemma about black ball shifting, we have now proven :

> Any configuration in which there are two boxes, each containing at least one black and one white ball, is strictly inferior to some other configuration.

Because one of those configurations is better than the other, but then continuous black-ball shifting makes both of them inferior to a configuration in which one of the boxes has no black ball.

---

###### Proving that two boxes must have only white balls

Therefore, we may stick to configurations in which there is at most one box, say Box $1$, which contains both black and white balls. The other configurations either contain no white ball, or no black ball (but not both : the problem is not well-defined if any $T_i=0$).

The situation where every box either consists of only white or black balls leads to a success probability of at most $\frac 23$ , and we know that can be bettered. So we will stick to box $1$ being the box that has both white and black balls.

Suppose that box $2$ contains a black ball. Then, by our earlier assertion, it contains only black balls, which means that $a_2 = 0$. Therefore, we trivially have $$
a_2T_1(T_1-1) < a_1T_2(T_2+1)
$$

By the exchange inequality, it follows that a better configuration is formed by transferring a black ball from Box $1$ to Box $2$. However, using the inductive shifting lemma, this means that we eventually arrive at the situation where Box $1$ has only white balls and Box $2$ has only black balls. Knowing that Box $3$ also only has either white or black balls, it follows that this configuration has success probability at most $\frac 23$, which we know can be bettered.

We have shown that :

> In any optimal configuration, the two boxes that have balls of only one color in it can consist only of white balls. That is, without loss of generality, $b_1=7,b_2=b_3=0$.

---

###### To finish off

To finish, we must only see what is the best among those configurations with $b_1=7,b_2=b_3=0$. In this case, the success probability explicitly equals $$
\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{a_1}{a_1+7}+\frac{2}{3}\right]
$$

Thus, we must maximize this quantity , subject to $a_2,a_3>0$ (so that the other boxes are not empty). That is easily done : write $$
\frac{1}{3}\left[\frac{a_1}{a_1+7}+\frac{2}{3}\right] = \frac{1}{3}\left[1-\frac{7}{a_1+7}+\frac{2}{3}\right]
$$

Now, the bigger the value of $a_1$, the bigger the above quantity. The biggest possible value of $a_1$ is $21$, with $a_2=a_3=1$. It follows that $$
a_1=21,a_2=a_3=1, b_1=7,b_2=b_3=0
$$

is the best configuration.

---

###### ADDENDUM

The exchange argument is actually a heavily used technique in queue and scheduling theory. Whenever the "reward" (or "cost") tends to have a structure that corresponds well with exchanges, then one can make use of these arguments to *rigorously* prove the optimality of various strategies (typically "greedy" strategies like the above one, where you believe that some kind of monotonicity is at play. Indeed, monotonicity plays a huge role in optimal control theory).

Answer (score 1):

First off, we know there has to be at least one white stone in each, or you would cap out at $\frac 2 3$ which is less than what you have.

We can limit what we look at by just considering how many boxes have black stones in them.

The first case is putting all the bad apples in one box.  Obviously in that case the  best thing to do is to only put a single white in the other 2 and use the remaining 21 to dilute the influence of the 7, which is what you achieved above.

If we have 2 cases with black stones, then we only need 1 white in the third box,   so we have 22 white to distribute amongst the two remaining, mixed with 7 black stones.
So, your black stones could be 6 and 1, 5 and 2,  or 4 and 3.  Obviously no single box can have as big a loss potential as $\frac 1 4$,  so at a floor we need to triple the white stones:

Box 1:  6 black and 18 white
Box 2:  1 black and 3 white
This gives each of these the same $\frac 1 4$ as before,  totaling double the loss potential!   We only have a single white stone we can add left to bring one of them slightly below $\frac 1 4$,   so we have a loss potential of $\frac 1 12$ from the better worst box,  and something nonzero from the better box,  thus it is a worst scenario
Similarly with the other configurations, you need 3* as many white as black,  so 21 white, 7 black...only one box can be improved a tiny bit

Now lets say you have black stones in all 3 boxes.   Once again,  the very worst box  we can allow as a loss $\frac 1 4$,  so we need to use 21 white to match the 7 black...leaving us only 2 white stones left to improve the odds.  THe best we ccan do is improve the odds of 1 or 2 of the boxes,  leaving the third at a $\frac 1 4$ failure rate, and the other two at nonzero failure rates,  thus all are worse than the single black box case.